# Objective-C & Swift 2.0 and "paranoic" Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift2

On a Project i use Objective-c 2.0-Swift2.0 and XCode 7.0.

So the matter is:
I'm tryin to put some string gotten from txt file in order to be shown into a UiTextView object. 
The catch from another Object-C call was fine.
The reading of the file txt Was fine

...but the putting String into the UITextView! returns me always Nil. It's a dummy work but... it's still not work!

I tried to do the same as single Application Swift File: it works!
p.s. Notice i did a IBoutlet to connect the UIView Object into the StoryBoard to this Class.

Here's the code, if you need more details i would be happy to provide this.

```
import UIKit

@objc(TextControllerSwift) class TextControllerSwift: UIViewController {
var textRoom: String?
var textPlaying: String?

@IBOutlet weak var textMuseum: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    realplay()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func playText(textSelect: String) {
//textSelect REturn a string value from another Object-C Class -See comments in the Segue add in.

    textPlaying = textSelect
 }

 func realPlay(){

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(textPlaying, ofType:"txt")

    if (path != nil){
        //read the file
        do {
            let textRoom = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(textRoom)
        }
        catch {/* let's ignore when i didn't find file */}

        textMuseum!.text="pippo"  //Nil 
       print(textMuseum!.text)    //Nil 

  textMuseum.text=textMuseum.text.stringByAppendingString(String(textRoom))  //Nil 
    }
}}
```

it give me 
"**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**"

Why? Why? in the same project i call another Swift Class and it works really fine. (AKA i followed the guideline for coexisting Swift&Objective-C classes)
Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

**EDIT:** Added info about the Caller from Objective-C, maybe this helps.

```
   `if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueIntroTesto"]) {

    NSLog(@"%@ in segueIntroTesto" , selectedIntroFilm);
    TextControllerSwift *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    [destViewController playText:selectedIntroFilm];
    }`
```

**EDIT2:**: removed `*self.viewDidLoad()*` under playText func.

**EDIT3:**: splitted the function `playText()` into another Function to give time to XCode (uffff) to get the new View then i REMOVED the old damned Outlet :D ...cheers I solved Thanks

Comment: If you set a breakpoint and step through the code, which line gives the error?

Comment: where i put //Nil comment....

Comment: Why do you have `self.viewDidLoad()` inside `playText` ? remove that. from my experience sometimes when you try to work with `IBOutlets` when inside `viewDidLoad` they are still nil, try instead in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: oh i forgot it to remove it as i added to "trying" to get some ideas. BTW the result was and it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to set the value of an outlet before the view gets loaded.  Preparing for a segue happens before outlets are filled in.

Pass `selectedIntroFilm` into the controller and save it as a property during the segue, then call `playText` later...during `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` or whatever makes sense for the app.

Comment: You mean the `TextControllerSwift ` isn't loaded? that's why i put the `DidLoad` to try loading the View. 
As i did the `DidLoad` should the Controller be started no?

on your hint so i call a new method where it store the  `selectedIntroFilm` then i call `DidLoad` with `playText` inside. 
Should it works? i'll try, thanks for the idea.

Comment: It doesn't have its views loaded or its outlets.  **You don't have to call any `DidLoad` method; the OS does that for you.** You only need to decide what you want to do once loading is complete.

Comment: not working... hmm that's a challenge.
`2015-10-03 22:13:17.693 xxxxxx[3685:946750] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TextControllerSwift 0x12e503a00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: **bold**this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key testo.'**bold**
*** First throw call stack:
...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

as i checked this return to "segue" perform...then get to launch the TextControllerSwift, i suppose...

Comment: Different problem: you have some outlet called `testo` defined in your storyboard or xib and no matching property in your class.

Comment: right: ... removed the original Outlet, altought i'm surprised.

Comment: Great! the hidden outlet was the problem. I put two outlet ... but i forgot to remove the first one and now it works. Thank you a lot!
now i have to fix the put of string... but is a different issue. :D